# PHP. Can any one help me with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, forms

I have html code including  elements.
What I am trying to do is, I need the whole html code of this form element.
For example, in the html code below

```
...
<p>Sample</p>
<img src="..." />
<form method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" value="v1" id="v1" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" value="v2" name="v2">
    ...
</form>
<div>...</div>
...
```

I want to extract these codes:

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" value="v1" id="v1" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" value="v2" name="v2">
    ...
</form>
```

Since I am not so familiar with preg_match expression, I hardly can figure it out.
I googled to understand expressions myself, but only could get small portion of grasp.

Can any one help me, please?
Best regards.

Comment: [Thou shalt not use regular expressions to parse (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html). The accepted answer to the linked question should give you the necessary hints.

Comment: @Linus: Don't forget the classic *[You can't parse XHTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732454)*

Comment: @grawity Yes. My all-time favorite. I alternate between this one and the other when taking out the XHTML-regex-whip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expession to match the form tag may look like this: "`(?smi)<form.*?</form>`"

**EDIT 1**: In PHP the function call will look like this: `preg_match('/^.*?<form.*?<\/form>.*$/smi', $data)`

**EDIT 2**: This can be tested here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

But in general case I wouldn't advise as well to use regular expressions for parsing HTML code.

Comment: what does the (?smi) part do?

Comment: In Perl regular expressions it switches on the flags to match ^ and $ for line start and end (m), match dot for new line characters (s) and be case-insenstive (i)

Answer (score 1):

For something as trivial as matching a form tag in html, just don't use regular expressions or third party xhtml parsers.

Use the the default [DOM Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

It's as simple as :

```
// Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure 
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 

// Load the html's contents into DOM 
$xml->loadHTML($html); 

$forms = array(); 

//Loop through each <form> tag in the dom and add it to the $forms array 
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('form') as $form) { 
    //Get the node's html string
    $forms[] = $form->ownerDocument->saveXML($form); 
}
```

where `$forms` is an array of string of every forms.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to handle HTML is generally not a good idea. I'd rather suggest to use a HTML parser. I had good results with this library: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/